# How to Join two tables to get this result

Tags: sql-server

I am working on two tables similar to the tables below, please help me on my query to have a result similar to the third table. tnx in advance.

Table_Plan

```
JobID   Work_A  WorkA_Plan_Hrs  Work_B  WorkB_Plan_Hrs
1111    1111-a  20  1111-b  30
2222    2222-a  25  2222-b  50
```

Table_Actual

```
JobID   Work    Actual_Hrs  Finished
1111    1111-a  21  13:00
1111    1111-b  32  14:00
2222    2222-a  27  15:00
2222    2222-b  55  16:00
```

Desired Result

```
JobID   Work_A  WorkA_Plan_Hrs  Work_B  WorkB_Plan_Hrs  Actual_A    Actual_B    Act_Finished_B  Act_Finished_B
1111    1111-a  20  1111-b  30  21  32  13:00   14:00
2222    2222-a  25  2222-b  50  27  55  15:00   16:00
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Where's your attempt on this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with two lefts joins to `table_actual`, one for `Work_A` and one for `Work_B`.

```
select
    p.JobId
  , p.Work_A
  , p.WorkA_Plan_Hrs
  , p.Work_B
  , p.WorkB_Plan_Hrs
  , a.Actual as Actual_A
  , b.Actual as Actual_B
  , a.Finished as Act_Finished_A
  , b.Finished as Act_Finished_B
from table_plan p
  left join table_actual a
    on p.JobId = a.JobId
   and p.Work_A = a.Work
  left join table_actual b
    on p.JobId = b.JobId
   and p.Work_B = b.Work
```

Comment: Thanks a lot SqlZim... it worked perfect...  now I want to add a Done column showing 0,1, or 2 based on how many work is already finished. I am adding a CASE WHEN function like: CASE WHEN Actual_B > 1  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN Actual_B >1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Done, the error msg states that Actual_A is not valid column. Can you help me to get away with this..... Thanks again...

Comment: I already have find the answer, I have used a.Actual instead of Actual_A.... Thanks a lot again....